# "For the heartbeat he dared to hope."

Tags: phrase-meaning

> For the heartbeat he dared to hope.

From a quick search of the dictionary, I was able to gather the meaning of sentence, but am still unsure. (It is from Game of Thrones Song of Ice and Fire.)

Comment: You haven't given much context, but "a heartbeat" is often used to denote the period of time between two heart beats - perhaps a second or so.

Answer (score 2):

You have misquoted it. It is not:

> For the heartbeat he dared to hope.

but rather:

> For a heartbeat he dared to hope.

This could be "translated" as:

> For the duration of a heartbeat, he let himself hope.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be meaningful in context if you are relating to Game of Thrones. It means that he hoped that there would be a heartbeat because heartbeat signifies life and absence of it means the presence of death beyond the wall which was something fearful.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I changed some grammatical errors and typos. Please pay more attention when you post another answer.  Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.